# how to modify the last call log in android

Tags: android, call, android-contacts

I am working on an android project. I would like to ask how to modify the last call log (phone number). I am using an incoming broadcast receiver so I know when incoming calls arrive. Need some advice. Appreciate

Comment: what have you done already? did you try to search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems like a duplicate of [Delete call from call log after call end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361429/delete-call-from-call-log-after-call-end).

There is a content provider you can use to search for certain calls and delete them. Look at the question that I linked.