# Delete call log in android for particular number

Tags: java, android, calllog

I am trying to delete all call logs of particular number.

```
try {
    String strNumberOne[] = {number};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + "=? ", strNumberOne, "");
    boolean bol = cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (bol) {
        do {
            int idOfRowToDelete = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls._ID));                            
            getContentResolver().delete(Uri.withAppendedPath(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(idOfRowToDelete)), "", null);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.print("Exception here ");
}
```

I want to fire a `LIKE` query, because the mobNum saved in callLog is +916666666666 and i am passing number 6666666666. so its not matching. can anybody help me to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following links:

- [Call log deletion in Android](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/androidcalllogdeletion/)
- [SO: Delete call from call log after call end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361429/delete-call-from-call-log-after-call-end)

Comment: Please see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @umesh, can you share the answer?

Comment: The second link is not working now. Can someone please share how it could be done?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code to delete any particular number from history

```
String number="4666";//any number
Uri CALLLOG_URI = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls"); 
context.getContentResolver().delete(CALLLOG_URI,CallLog.Calls.NUMBER +"=?",new String[]{number});
```

you can also delete call log by user name  by doing this

```
context.getContentResolver().delete(CALLLOG_URI,CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME +"=?",new String[]{name});
```