# How to send SMS from the Android app without making its record in device SMS view?

Tags: android, sms

I want to send an SMS from my android app. But I don't want its record to be exist in device message view. I am currently using below code.

```
sendSMS(etsendernumber.getText().toString(), etmessagebody.getText().toString()); 
sendintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendintent.putExtra("sms_body","");
sendintent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendintent);
```

But it is making sent sms record in message view of the device. Can we send a secret sms from android application?

Please advice.

Comment: In android KitKat 4.4.2 ,you will send sms using this code,that sms are will be record in default sms application

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the way you are trying to send SMS is by using the shipped messaging application. So it will always record the sent messages. You must use SmsManager to send the SMS.

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

In this way, your SMS wont be inserted into the list.

Also remember to add this in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Can we delete calls from call logs also? I mean I want to delete last made call from call logs.

Comment: Follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019684/delete-call-log-in-android-for-particular-number

Comment: In android KitKat 4.4.2 ,you will send sms using this code,that sms are will be record in default sms application.

Comment: @Jimmer How i can filter my sending message in KitKat ? my app is not a defult sms application , just i want send sms with out show in in inbox in any version of android.plz help me

Comment: This wont work, on message will display in your outbox in M

Comment: Yes, they have changed the implementation for M, only works till L.

Answer (score 1):

If you use android SMS application to send message then it would save that message in the outbox or sent. What you can do is delete that message from the sms database.
After sending sms Delete that message using this:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox"), "address = ? and body = ?", new String[] {etsendernumber.getText().toString(),etmessagebody.getText().toString()});
```

If msg is in out box

OR

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), "address = ? and body = ?", new String[] {etsendernumber.getText().toString(),etmessagebody.getText().toString()});
```

If message is in sent items.

Comment: Thanks for posting. Can we delete calls from call logs also? I mean I want to delete last made call from call logs

Comment: Never did this, but I think it can be done. But if you want answers, I think you should ask another question. :)

Comment: Doesn't worked for me. :(
Should I request any extra permission (AndroidManifest.xml)?

Comment: Only default messaging app can delete