# Android 4.4 sent SMS Stored in Inbox

Tags: android

In Android 4.4, My App is not an SMS App but it need to send SMS(multiple times).
The thing is that the Sent SMS will be stored in Default SMS App(Hangouts).
It would spam/annoy users a lots. I would like the SMS actions are transparent/silently with End-Users.

AFAIK, we may prevent this by setting my App at the moment I send the SMS & change back later.
But this is not really an option since end-user flow become complicated & may lead to confusion. another reason is Default SMS App may lose the System Broadcast when my App was set as Default SMS App.

Is there complete solution on this?

Thank you for you support.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong.. you want to send sms without storing in default sentitems list..????

The task you mentioning is possible without any confusion in the flow...

This can be done by setting the `sentIndent` in `smsmanager` to `null`.

```
public final void sendTextMessage (String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

This will suppress the `sentintent` thereby avoiding to store in the default sent items...

There is also a previously discussed question regarding this topic in stackoverflow..

[How to send SMS from the Android app without making its record in device SMS view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217715/how-to-send-sms-from-the-android-app-without-making-its-record-in-device-sms-vie)

Check it out...

If you could share the code u use for sending message.. It would be more easy to help for others...

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Below is the current code I'm using.

SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(serverNumber, null, smsContent, null, null);

Comment: Did you tryout by setting highest priority for our app??? for send_sms intent in manifest???
<intent-filter android:priority="1000">

Comment: already tried but no success

` <intent-filter android:priority="1000" >
  <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
 </intent-filter>`

Comment: It would be so frustrating for you sorry for it. did you tried abortBroadcast()???? after sending mess???

Comment: i feel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20027658/sms-received-in-my-sms-app-and-in-hangouts-although-i-call-abortbroadcast this question will hep you... but there too they said no solution for your situation since hangouts came into play as DEFAULT APP :(