# Android how to delete call log after finishing the outgoing call

Tags: android, phone-call, calllog

I am developing an application in which i want to delete the entry in the call log which is the last outgoing call number. I need to do this when i am finished the outgoing call. The issue I am facing is I cannot retrieve the last dialled number from CallLog when the call is finished. I have used the PhoneStateListener and tried to capture the IDLE state. Still no luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019684/delete-call-log-in-android-for-particular-number

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I need to hide call logs from perticular contact, can you help me regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have following permission in manifast.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

for Deleting Calllogs for particular number try this way:

```
public void DeleteCallLogByNumber(String number) {   
    String queryString="NUMBER="+number; 
    this.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,queryString,null);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But the problem is I cannot get the number to be deleted when the call is finished. It take some time to populate the number in call log.