# I have been making an app for which I want to maintain a private call log for all my calls. Can someone please help me out with this

Tags: android

[How do I access call log for android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786666/how-do-i-access-call-log-for-android)
found this but this gives me an access to my existing call log. I want to make private call log in which some specified numbers will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

A "private call log" is simply a list (or `ListView` activity).

You can use the same layouts and fonts as the "default" android app, but remember that each carrier and manufacturer re-brands the call logs on almost every phone.

So you just need to make your own. You can monitor call logs and remove them if you don't want them duplicated in both logs. See this post:

[Delete call log in android for particular number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019684/delete-call-log-in-android-for-particular-number)