# Android - Hide calling phone number when call is made through my app?

Tags: android, phone-call, calllog

I have button in my Android app to call a desired phone number.

I want to hide this number from callers call log (Yes, I want to hide it from displaying androids call log) is there any possible way for me to display calls made by my app as strings (Eg. if you call 12345678; i want to display it as "my numb")

This is my current code to make the call

```
public void callUsNow(View v) {
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
    con.startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

Could anyone suggest on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361429/delete-call-from-call-log-after-call-end ?

Comment: Tried it. but got an error.. saying cannot delete the URL: content://call_log/calls/1

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you pass Intent by calling `Intent.ACTION_CALL`, after `con.startActivity(callIntent)` other activity will have control over it.