# How can we hide call logs of specific contact in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, calllog, incoming-call

I am trying to hide call logs from particular contact. For this I have created broadcast receiver for receive event of incoming / outgoing / missed call / call hangup.

But how can I get call details on call hangup event ?

I know we can get following 2 informations when incoming event occurs :

**1) State

 2) Phone Number**

Now for hide contact, I need to delete entry from defalut call log database which is located in **“content://call_log/calls”**., and insert it inside my sqlite database.

Is there anybody who faced this kind of issue before ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better approach would be to register a **ContentOberver** on the call log table. See this question: [How to implement a ContentObserver for call logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422410/how-to-implement-a-contentobserver-for-call-logs)

Whenever an update is made to the table, you could query for the phone number in question and delete the  record.

Comment: Thanks for sharing :) Let me do some research and implementation using this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361429/delete-call-from-call-log-after-call-end you can also try this..