# Android 4.1+: Change number before it is written to the call log?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a little app that intercepts outgoing calls and changes the number before it is dialed. 
Naturally, then the modified number is written to the call log. I want to add an option to put the original number to the call log. I already found out that it is possible to read and write the call log.

Is there also an intent before the log entry is written where I can easily change the number before it is stored to the log instead of editing after it is written, comparable to 
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />`?

Answer (score 0):

Here [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477889/intent-to-be-fired-when-a-call-ends) I read that you can intercept the action of "ending call" for example, and after that I guess you could try to erase the modified number from the log (that you already realized) and then write the original one

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the fact, that I can read/write/modify the call log and also that there is a way to get notified of ended calls. However, I would love to have a direct way to modifiy the number similar to changing the number on outgoing calls. I did quite some research on this topic and did not find anything, therefore it might not exist - this question here is my last hope :)